# document.getElementById ( )

Tags: javascript

I am using the w3school.com JavaScript compiler to test basic programs as I go along learning JavaScript.

The first thing I have noticed is in the following snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>    
<p>My first paragraph</p>    
<p id = "demo"></p>    

<script>

 var x = 4;
 var y = 8;
 var z = x + y;
 var car = "Fiat";

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
 //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = car;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I uncomment the second `document.getElementById` the first one (`12`) is no longer displayed; i.e. only `Fiat` is shown. Why is that? How do I simply display more than one variable content?

Comment: Both statements alter the contents of the same element, so if you run both statements, the second one will overwrite the changes made by the first one.

Comment: Never heard of the "w3school.com Javascript compiler " before this lol :p

Comment: Real progammers stay out from w3schools use the browser's console like you should

Comment: I block w3schools results in my google searches. See http://www.w3fools.com/ .

Comment: @Tex You might want to go reread that page.  It's changed somewhat.

Comment: @Tex Can you do that!! I switched to DuckDuckGo just to avoid getting the Spanish translation of all manuals?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález You can do it in Chrome using a browser extension called "Personal Blocklist". James Thorpe: Sorry, not interested in w3schools.

Comment: Thank you all.  Got it.  I tried using VS2010 for Javascript (by following [link](http://technostropic.com/2013/06/06/node-js-development-part-2-visual-studio-and-node-js/) but could not get it to work. For an absolute beginner, is there a better tutorial to get started with Javascript in VS2010?

Comment: W3Schools has flaws, but then so does MDN. Neither one is perfect.

Comment: @Tex I'm not really interested in w3schools either - I'm just saying you might want to re-read what w3fools has to say these days.  It's far from their original message - _"they have at least worked on the primary concern developers had"_

Comment: @rojobo I can open the browser's console by pressing `Shift+Ctrl+J` and of course I can issue single commands such as `console.log("Hello world");` but how do I run JavaScript programs; e.g. the one in this topic?

Comment: @Joshua you get yourself a basic HTML template like the one above and include your .js file and start building your own programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** property of element which will remove the existing html content with the new html content.

> Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.(*[Taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Syntax)*)

Then you can combine multiple string using simple string concatenation

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z + '<br/>' + car;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br/>' + car;
```

---

**FYI :** Updating `innerHTML` property is not a good idea to use since it will regenerate all html elements and it will remove the all attached event handlers to the inner elements. So be cautious while using it.

Comment: You can drop the `/` now too - especially since OP is explicitly using the HTML5 doctype - `<br>` is just fine :)

Comment: Can we please not teach beginners to use `.innerHTML += "..."`? Sure it's innocuous here, but they end up using it everywhere. There's just no need for it at all.

Answer (score 1):

> When I uncomment the second document.getElementById the first one (12)
>   is no longer displayed

---

This is because you are overwriting the content of the element with id `demo` in your uncommented line. You should either use two different elements to show different contents or append the content to the same element by using `+`

Either do :

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = z;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = car;
```

or follow what Pranav has suggested.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining the behavior that was puzzling me.

Comment: Happy to help.  :)